# Weird Field Permissions

Tags: custom-field, permissions, profile, permission-sets, roles

I have a field (checkbox) that is inexplicably inaccessible by most users even if they're in the profile that allows them access to it. I've checked the field level security and it says it's editable by all profiles, and accessibility says it's editable in all layouts. Even if two users have the same profile and role levels, one will be able to edit it and the other will not. I tried cheating with a permission set where I explicitly allow editing of that field only, but it didn't help at all. It's bad enough that even the admin isn't allowed to edit it. As of right now I know of only three users that are capable of editing it and even blindly matching other users to their roles/profiles doesn't help. I tried checking with perm-comparator, but nothing odd stood out for me.

Is there any other place I should be looking into to try and figure out why this one field is so darn hard to edit?

Comment: Is this field being displayed on a Visualforce page or a standard layout?

Comment: Standard layout.

Comment: What is the Sharing settings defined for the object in which this field exist ? You may want to check if these 3 users are able to get the edit permission through some sharing rule.

Comment: Does the admin still have a profile with the Modify All Data permission?

Comment: The admin profile does indeed still have the Modify All Data permission set to true.

Comment: @Dave the field is on the Opportunity object, which has it's default sharing rules, so I don't think there's anything wrong with that.

Comment: @Alex , is it only this field which has permission issue or is it the whole object ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, it is only that field that has the permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the error message that you are getting? Or is the field grayed out?

Could it be that the 3 people have a different page layout setting?

On the page layout, you can set if a field is read-only or not.

[image: set field required]

Last thing to check is if there's a validation rule preventing people from editing the field.

Comment: Field is not grayed out and all layouts have the field as fully accessible, i.e. the read-only and required checkboxes are both set to false. There's no validation rules that would prevent the field from being changed.